# How to Access private listed video from YouTube to my website using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I want to access YouTube private listed videos from my YouTube account, using my API key. I am getting publicly listed video using the API key, but I am stuck trying to get a list of privately listed videos.

Please help me out with this issue. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
YouTubeService yt = new YouTubeService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    { ApiKey = "key" });

var searchListRequest = yt.Search.List("snippet");
searchListRequest.ChannelId = "channelid";

var searchListResult = searchListRequest.Execute();
foreach (var item in searchListResult.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID:" + item.Id.VideoId);
    Console.WriteLine("snippet:" + item.Snippet.Title);
}
```

Comment: an API key only lets you access data that is already public. If you want to access private data then you need to make your application log in to the API and get an access token. There are tutorials, samples etc available covering this process.

Answer (score 1):

API keys can only be used to access public data, an example of a public would be the [Youtube video search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) which would return all public videos.

Private videos on your account can only be viewed by you if you want your application to be able to access them then you will need to use Oauth2 to authenticate your application so that it can read your private videos. using [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Comment: Please provide me the code sample in c# for the private video list